# Local notifications in codename one

Tags: codenameone

[image]From which version of android tablets will local notification support in codename?

I was tried with my tablet version 4.2.2 but its not giving any notifications.Its working fine for mobiles and ipad's and iphones.How do i resolve the issue to get the notifications on android tablets with the version 4.2 or below.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for older tablets. I'm assuming that this is a Kindle tablet and not a google authorized tablet.

The latter doesn't have Google Play Services installed and this effectively disables a lot of the features builtin to Android.

Comment: I have used Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1 espresso10wifi GT-P5113 with version 4.0.4 eventhough i didn't get the alerts.

Comment: You tried to edit my answer with code representing background fetch. It's unclear if the background fetch is failing or what really is failing there. I suggest connecting the device with a cable and looking thru the DDMS output to see if errors are printed.

Comment: shai,
i am updating records in db while background fetch calling ,records are updated also. Here the problem is only with the notifications

Comment: Thanks for the log, I think I see an issue here. We'll look into it.

Comment: Hi shai ,is there any update for me regarding the notifications?

Comment: We made a fix that might solve this. Check after Friday.

Comment: Hai shai,i gave the build today though i am getting the same error log which i have posted earlier.Please suggest me the solution to solve the problem.

Comment: I see another place where this is used. We'll try again this Friday.